# php if statement (how to check the user input duplicate record)

Tags: php, mysql

how to check the input between users and database whether it is duplicate?
This is the form for the user to input data to database
And This code's result will be work whether it saves same or not same records.

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("booking", $con);

    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $classroom = $_POST['classroom']; 
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $s=implode(" ",$subject);
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `year` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    $result=mysql_query("$sql1");
    $row =mysql_fetch_row($result);




        $sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`year`, `month`, `day`, `time`, `classroom`,`subject`) VALUES  ('$year','$month','$day','$time','$classroom','$s')";



    ?>
```

I wrote a code that I think that can determine the same records
if same , user can not input.
if not same user can input.
The code represent like this :

```
if($row[1]==$year){ 
　   echo'the data was repeated';
```

can anyone help to solve my if-statement problem?

Update:

```
if($row[1]==$year){ 
　   echo'the data was repeated';} else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`year`, `month`, `day`, `time`, `classroom`,`subject`) VALUES  ('$year','$month','$day','$time','$classroom','$s')";}
```

I wrote this syntax error....(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in )
Should I use While-loop to rewrite?
Could you please  tell me how to correct the code?

Comment: One thing you can do is that have the condition of comparison in the select query and then call the block of the insert only if select query returns null.

Answer (score 2):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("booking", $con);

$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$classroom = $_POST['classroom']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$s=implode(" ",$subject);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`year`, `month`, `day`, `time`, `classroom`,`subject`) VALUES  ('$year','$month','$day','$time','$classroom','$s')";
$qr = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$qr) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

And the mysql.... You need to change the typs...

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classroom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `year` (`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place unique index on year column in mysql. That will be unique years for all users.

Probably you need unique index on 2 fields (year + userID)

Comment: i have updated my code and can you pls read my problem? thank you Very much